# How to split string and push in array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var string = 'a,b,c,d';
var array = [];
```

As we can see above I have one string values with separator**(,)**. I want to split these values and wants to push in the array. At last I want to read my array by using for loop. Please suggest.

Comment: Why would you use jQuery for this?

Comment: Use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var array = string.split(',');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var string = 'a,b,c,d',
    strx   = string.split(',');
    array  = [];

array = array.concat(strx);
// ["a","b","c","d"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery for that, you can do it with normal javascript:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var str = "a,b,c,d";
var res = str.split(","); // this returns an array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = string.split(",");
```